# Encountered activationStatus has been modified externally when publishing

Tags: magnolia

I'm doing an update for multiple nodes and then a batch publish (a lot of data) using the command "Activate" to publish the nodes programmatically but sometimes I don't know why I will get an error sometimes. It only happened for few times so far so I find it hard to figure out what's the one causing the issue.

Here is the error thrown.

```
Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.StaleItemStateException: 8b3ce2d4-eb7b-4838-901c-413aa9eeee84/{http://www.magnolia.info/jcr/mgnl}activationStatus has been modified externally
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemSaveOperation.removeTransientItems(ItemSaveOperation.java:723)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemSaveOperation.perform(ItemSaveOperation.java:228)
```

Have anyone encountered a similar issue? Or any idea where to look at this issue?

Thanks! :)

Comment: I assume you are using async commands therefore one may change its state till the other one handles the case. If you do this programmatically I'd suggest to try if it helps to have some Thread.sleep() time between. If the problem is indeed the timing, we can do something about it such as listening when the operation is done etc etc.

Comment: Hi @Ducaz035, is this command async?                                               I'm executing this one: 
        Command cmd = ((CommandsManager) Components.getComponent(CommandsManager.class)).getCommand("", "activate");
        Context ctx = new SimpleContext();
        Map params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("repository", workspaceName);
        params.put("uuid", uuid);
        params.put("recursive", true);

        ctx.putAll(params);
        cmd.execute(ctx);

Comment: Also, I dont quite understand what happened actually? why is activationStatus modified externally? there's only one author instance and no one is touching the public instance also except this author instance. Can you help explain the case where this could happen? Thanks a lot!

Comment: which version pls?

Comment: @JenSze To clarify it: Do you  update of the nodes and directly trying to publish them? I assumed that update of the nodes changes the publication status (which it should) and then you have the issue.

Comment: I'm using magnolia 5.4.7, @Ducaz035, yes you're correct, i'm updating the nodes and publishing them directly by using the code. I'm not allowed to do it like that? So what's the correct way to do it to avoid the issue? Sorry ah, I'm still a bit confused how it became an issue. Can you enlighten me? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically update operation internally cause Magnolia to modify the activation state (which is correct). When this operation is ongoing the update operation is taking over and attempting to change the state. In this case if you are unlucky you might hit the exception you got. Reasoning being is that those commands run async but touch the same nodes.

Potential Solution:

1) You may simply give some time for the first operation to complete and execute the second one after.

2) This needs some development effort but here we go:

You may use LockManager to lock the nodes being used by the first operation and unlock it when the operation is done completely. Second operation meanwhile will check if the nodes are locked and if yes will not continue but wait till its unlocked from the first process.

Comment: Ok noted thanks! I will try the first one. thanks! :)